# Wordpress search results page returning 404, but the records exist in the database

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I have 2 wordpress installations, 1 is for major content, the other is a help center.

the help center is installed in the major content directory. So you have the wordpress directory, and another in that directory, making it so we can use different themes and change the look between the two.

I'm just curious, on the search results page, I'm getting the correct url's, but they are going to 404 pages. I verified in the database that these records exist, so it's not a matter of the database not making these records and that these pages don't exist. Another note is that the search results page will return pages that have been created, but

```
<?php

get_header();
global $wp_query;
$total_result = $wp_query->found_posts;

?>

<div class="main">

  <div class="main-hero">

    <div class="container">

      <h1>Boxstorm Help Center</h1>
      <p>Search the Boxstorm Help Center documentation</p>

      <div class="search-wrapper">

            <form id="searchform" class="searchform" role="search" method="get" action="<?php echo site_url(); ?>">
              <div>
                <label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">Search for:</label>
                <input id="s" name="s" type="text" placeholder="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search &hellip;', 'placeholder', 'boxstorm' ); ?>" value="<?php echo get_search_query(); ?>">
                <span class="search-button-wrapper">
                  <input id="searchsubmit" type="submit" value="">
                  <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                </span>
              </div>
            </form>


      </div><!-- / .search-wrapper -->

    </div>

  </div><!-- /.main-hero -->

  <nav class="main-hero-subnav cd-secondary-nav">

    <div class="container">
      <div class="is-hidden-mobile">
        <?php get_breadcrumb(); ?>
      </div>
    </div>

  </nav>

  <div class="panel sub-nav-hero">

    <div class="container page">

      <div class="columns is-multiline is-mobile search-results">

        <div class="column is-3-desktop is-6-tablet is-full-mobile left">
          <div class="columns top-cats is-multiline is-mobile is-centered">

            <div class="column is-11-desktop is-10-tablet is-6-mobile">
              <div>
                <a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/getting-started/">
                  <i class="fas fa-list-ul"></i>
                  <h2>Getting Started</h2>
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="column is-11-desktop is-10-tablet is-6-mobile">
              <div>
                <a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/documentation/">
                  <i class="fas fa-book"></i>
                  <h2>Documentation</h2>
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="column is-11-desktop is-10-tablet is-6-mobile">
              <div>
                <a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/videos/">
                  <i class="far fa-play-circle"></i>
                  <h2>Browse Videos</h2>
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="column is-11-desktop is-10-tablet is-6-mobile">
              <div>
                <a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/contact/">
                  <i class="fas fa-at"></i>
                  <h2>Contact Support</h2>
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="column is-9-desktop is-6-tablet is-full-mobile right">
          <h1 class="results"><?php printf( __( 'Search results for: <b>%s</b>', 'boxstormsupport'), get_search_query() ); ?></h1>

            <div class="columns is-multiline">

              <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); get_template_part( 'content', 'search' ); ?>
              <div class="column is-12 results">
                <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="results-link"><?php the_permalink(); ?></a>
              </div>
              <?php endwhile; else : ?>
              <div class="column is-12">
                <p><?php _e( '<p>Sorry, but there were no results for the term <b style="font-weight:900;">'.get_search_query().'</b>. Please refine your search terms and try again.</p>' ); ?></p>
              </div>
              <?php endif; ?>
            </div><!-- / columns -->

        </div><!-- / columns is-9 right -->

      </div><!-- / search-results -->
    </div>

  </div>

</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

The site is live at https://www.boxstorm.com/help-center. If you'd like to see the problem.

The pages follow this format in wordpress:

Pages parameters:

[image]

This is what I'm seeing:

Chrome
[image]
Firefox
[image]
Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Have you tried refreshing your permalinks? You go to Settings -> Permalinks -> click on "Save Changes".

Comment: @nullwriter I have tried this, the issue persists. Thanks for the suggestion though.